# In PHP can you use || (or) in the same way as javascript?

Tags: php, variables

Can I use the OR argument in this way in PHP? Meaning if $x is null assign $y to $var.

```
$var = $x || $y
```

Simple question, cheers!

Comment: You know you could have tried yourself... Just saying.

Comment: I was hoping it would enlighten me on the best practices for this type of scenario, and it has. This question will also act as reference for others.

Comment: For a reference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. PHP's boolean operators evaluate to `true` or `false`, not the value of the operands as in Javascript. So you'll have to write something like this:

```
$var = $x ? $x : $y;
```

Since 5.3, you can write this though, which basically has the same effect as Javascript's `||`:

```
$var = $x ?: $y;
```

That requires that `$x` exists though, otherwise you should check with `isset` first.

Answer (score 3):

No, in this way you assign a boolean to `$var`

```
$var = $x or $y;
```

means: `$var` is `true`, if `$x` or `$y`. You are looking for the ternary operator

```
$var = isset($x) ? $x : $y;
// or
$var = empty($x) ? $y : $x;
```

The ternary operator always works like

```
$var = $expressionToTest
     ? $valueIfExpressionTrue
     : $valueIfExpressionFalse
```

With PHP5.3 or later you can omit `$valueIfExpressionTrue`

```
$var = $expressionToTest ?: $valueIfExpressionFalse;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=0;
$y=9;
$var = ($x)?$x:$y;

echo $var;
```

if variable x is null then var will be 9,or else it will be value of x.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered, but I juist wanted to point your attention to the other usage of `OR` and `AND` operators in `PHP`

```
defined('SOMETHING') OR define('SOMETHING', 1);
```

if this case if `SOMETHING` is not defined (`defined('SOMETHONG')` evaluates to `false`) expression after `OR` will be evaluated

```
$admin AND show_admin_controls();
```

if `$admin` is evaluated to boolean `true`, `show_admin_controls()` function will be called

I usually use it to check if some constant is defined, but I've seen a lot of examples of good-looking and really well-readable code using this constructions for other purposes.